# How to conditionally add something to an array?

Tags: c#

Hello i am trying to use `if` statement when adding values to an array.

```
 object[] array = new object[10]
 {
    defect.RecordStation,
    defect.RecordUser,
    repairTypeDict[defect.Id],
    defect.Concern,
    defect.Comments,
    defect.RespCell,
    null,
    locationpartDict[defect.Id],
    if( repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id] == null)
       repairActualTimeDict[defect.Id];
    else
       repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id];
               ,
    defect.Id,
 };
```

i want to use the statement as 1 object

```
 if( repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id] == null)
    repairActualTimeDict[defect.Id];
 else
    repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id];
```

Thank you for help

Comment: `repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id] ?? repairActualTimeDict[defect.Id]`?

Comment: can you explain it please @PeterCsala

Comment: The `??` is called [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) and it works in the way if the left hand side is not null then take that value otherwise take the right hand side.

Comment: OT: Are you sure an anonymous object array is the best way to store something that should be its own class?

Comment: Okay Thank you so much good to know @PeterCsala. If you add your answer i will click okay.

Comment: your question seem to be more about using a replacement value in the case of null. I.e. As far as I can see it has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing you are right i should check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression

```
 if( repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id] == null)
    repairActualTimeDict[defect.Id];
 else
    repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id];
```

can be transformed to a single statement by using the `?:` [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

```
repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id] == null 
   ? repairActualTimeDict[defect.Id];
   : repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id];
```

or

```
repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id] != null 
   ? repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id]
   : repairActualTimeDict[defect.Id];;
```

The latter can be further simplified by `??` [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```
repairStandardTimeDict[defect.Id] ?? repairActualTimeDict[defect.Id]
```

Here if the left hand side is not null then take that value otherwise take the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the null coleascing operator which would be object **??** valueIfObjectNull.

What this means is if the object on the left of the operator is null, it will default to the value on the right of the operator.